# Get the last updated row of sql table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I i have a SQL Server database table called `tbl_faults`. In that table `fault_id` is a primary(int) and auto incremented. In the same table i have another field called `fault_reference` (int), and not auto incremented.

When i enter data to the table, `fault_reference` value should be the same value as `fault_id`.

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this.

```
$sql='SELECT Top 1 FROM "tbl_faults" ORDER BY "fault_id"';
```

I was trying to use this to get the last update value of `fault_id` and use it when inserting a new row, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get this by

```
$sql='SELECT Top 1 FROM "tbl_faults" ORDER BY "fault_id" DESC ';
```

To update your record I think you can use two methods.

1. Writing a trigger to update the row once insertion is done
2. Set fault_reference int NULL Allowed. Then write an update query to update rows fault_reference value as fault_id where fault_reference  is NULL.

This is just an idea. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT fault_id FROM tbl_faults ORDER BY fault_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Should give the last id that was inserted.

Comment: There is no `LIMIT` clause in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is better to do it in a single stored procedure, using [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function, which returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.
Because when you do it in a couple of batches there is possibility of `fault_id` being incremented in another batch.